# Getting specific values of key from Local Storage [JS][HTML5][React][LocalStorage]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-applications, local-storage

I have a problem to get the specific value of my key.
I created the array "UserLoggingData" (key) with the values of 'password','email' and 'id' (Time Stamp)
that are stored in the object User and saved in the local storage.
The parameters email and password are taken from a form.

```
let login_data =[];
const addUser = (ev)=>{
   ev.preventDefault();
   let user = {
       id : Date.now(),
       email:document.getElementById('email').value,
       password:document.getElementById('password').value
   }
   login_data.push(user);
   document.forms[0].reset();
   console.log(login_data);

   //save to local storage
   localStorage.setItem('UsersLoggingData',JSON.stringify(login_data));
```

Then I get such result in Local Storage:
[image: Result of me saved data]

How do I get to the specific password or email? How can I display them or get them so I can operate on them afterwards?
I tried `localStorage.getItem('UserLoggingData')`
but it shows null.
I need this for my diploma thesis so thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Do the opposite, use getItem and JSON.parse..

Comment: I tried this but it still shows up "null"    ----->      

"JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UserLoggingData'))"

Comment: `UserLoggingData`  is not the same as `UsersLoggingData`

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the string you will get from `localStorage.getItem()`. Once you've done this you will have an array (based on your screenshot). This code should log the first email in your console :

```
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(UsersLoggingData));
console.log(data[0].email)
```